# How to implement remote paging for iggrid with custom API

Tags: angular, typescript, ignite-ui, iggrid

I'm trying to integrate iggrid from Ignite UI to my SPA Angular 4 application.
I have custom API and I want to implement remote paging. My API has different names of parameters and returns items in content and total number in headers. I also need to add some headers to request.

Can I somehow do request by myself and just feed all necessary data to iggrid or do I really need to use iggrid to ask for data directly?

I know I can set iggrid datasource to array of data but if I do it this way I'm not able to set total count of items on the server.
I know I can use responseDataKey, but I don't know how to customize requests and how to tell grid to read data from headers.
I've already seen this: https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/108642/511554.aspx#511554

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Set the datasource array and on dataBinding specify the [totalRecordsCount](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2017.1/ig.treehierarchicaldatasource#methods:totalRecordsCount) with the datasource method.

```
        dataBinding: function(evt, ui) {
            ui.dataSource.totalRecordsCount(1234);
        },
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it works just on first binding. When I update IgGrid.dataSource, dataBind is not fired again. At the end I saved ui.dataSource in dataBinding event and set it when I was setting data.